# How can I log out users when they close their browser?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to make a chat room . In `Session_Start()` in Global.asax I have added user to Onlineusers list . And in `Session_End` I delete it from onlineusers table . But it removes the username after 20 minutes . How can i resolve this problem ?

Shall i use another method ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I said to you . I want to remove the user from onlineusers table immediatly . and I have tried to solve it but I wasn't Successful

Comment: How did you try to solve it?

Comment: By thinking about it . But i couldn't solve it

Comment: When you get past the thinking stage, let us know.

Comment: @JohnSaunders:- Do correct me if I am wrong but I think there is no guaranteed solution for this!!!

Comment: OH NO !!!!!! Realy? But what if a person shows me a solution? ;)

Comment: Then definitely I would be delighted to know that as it will enhance my knowledge too!!! ;)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: I didn't mean to suggest that he show a solution - you're right - there is none - but to show the steps he took in the direction of a solution. It would then be easier to point out why there is no actual solution.

Comment: @JohnSaunders:- Agreed to your point Sir. Actually I wrote that in my answer so I thought to confirm this.!!! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to do that. One workaround is that you can try and reduce the Session timeout in order to close inactive sessions faster. But this may have other bad consequences as well.

You may also check this [beforeunload | onbeforeunload event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**NOTE:-**

`Session_end` does not get fired when you close the browser. `Session_End` gets fired when the Session Timeout has expired. It happens on the server, and is completely independent of whether the user's browser is open or closed.

**EDIT:-**

As a workaround you may check this **[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/154801/How-to-end-user-session-when-browser-closed)** to do what you want.

Comment: Did you tried to use the Session End in your Global.asax class??

Comment: What is the Session Timeout value?/

Comment: have you stored the logged in variable in the session object, because when the session ends the person is automatically logged out?

Comment: yes ... when he/she clicks on the logout buttom it works immediatly but when he/she closes brwser it works after 20 mins.

Comment: how about using a cookie less authentication so that the authentication token is part of the url?

Comment: what should i exactly do?

Comment: As I already said that there is no guaranteed solution for this. But you may have a work around. You would be interested to check this link:- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/154801/How-to-end-user-session-when-browser-closed